# Pandas Data Frame correlation with Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a data frame and a series that I would like to return a rolling correlation as a new data frame.

So I have 3 columns in df1, I would like to return a new data frame that is the rolling correlation of each of these columns with a `Series` object.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('https://bpaste.net/raw/d0456d3a020b')
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1 = df1.set_index(df1['Date'])
del df1['Date']


df2 = pd.read_csv('https://bpaste.net/raw/d5cb455cb091')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2 = df2.set_index(df2['Date'])
del df2['Date']


pd.rolling_corr(df1, df2)
```

result https://bpaste.net/show/58b59c656ce4
gives NaNs and 1s only

```
pd.rolling_corr(df1['IWM_Close'], spy, window=22)
```

gives the ideal series returned, but I did not want to loop through the columns of the data frame. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your second input has to be a `Series` to be correlated with all `columns` in the first `DataFrame`.

This works:

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=date(2015,1,1), freq='W', periods = 100)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,3)), index=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,1)), index=index)
print(pd.rolling_corr(df1, df2.squeeze(), window=20).tail())
```

or, for the same result:

```
df2 = pd.Series(np.random.random(100), index=index)
print(pd.rolling_corr(df1, df2, window=20).tail())

                   0         1         2
2016-10-30 -0.170971 -0.039929 -0.091098
2016-11-06 -0.199441  0.000093 -0.096331
2016-11-13 -0.213728 -0.020709 -0.129935
2016-11-20 -0.075859  0.014667 -0.153830
2016-11-27 -0.114041  0.019886 -0.155472
```

but this doesn't - note the missing `.squeeze()` - only correlates the matching `columns`:

```
print(pd.rolling_corr(df1, df2, window=20).tail())

                   0   1   2
2016-10-30  0.019865 NaN NaN
2016-11-06  0.087075 NaN NaN
2016-11-13  0.011679 NaN NaN
2016-11-20 -0.004155 NaN NaN
2016-11-27  0.111408 NaN NaN
```